# Cannot kill redis server. It restarts every time I kill it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redis, daemon, systemctl

I cannot kill redis-server no matter how many times I've tried.

`ps -ef | grep redis-server` gives

`root       10592       1  0 01:10 ?        00:00:00 /snap/redis/658/usr/bin/redis-server *:6379`

`root       10846    8813  0 01:12 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto redis-server`

I have tried:

- Using kill -9 [pid]
- Using `service redis-server stop` (in normal user with sudo and while in `sudo su - root`)
- Using `/etc/init.d/redis-server stop`
- Using `redis-cli` and then running `shutdown SAVE` or `shutdown NOSAVE` in the CLI
- Using `systemctl stop redis-server`

No matter what I do, the server just restarts with a different PID. Can somebody tell me what the hell is going on? Yesterday, I never even installed redis on my Ubuntu. Today, after installing redis-cli, suddenly redis runs on boot, and is unkillable. What the hell is going on? How do I kill it? Why does it behave this way?

Note: I'm on Ubuntu 22.

Comment: It's a snap. If you don't need it you can uninstall it using `sudo snap remove redis-server`.

Comment: Ok, but why does it keep on restarting when I use snap? What's the reason behind that? Why is it unkillable through snap?

Comment: Possibly something else that you want depends on it.

Comment: Hm, not sure that's the case since I just installed it 2 days ago. Anyway, turns out `sudo snap stop redis` finally stops it. Don't know why snap processes are immune to normal kill commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turns out, snap uses a different system for maintaining processes vs regular systemctl. Snap apparently also allows you to start/stop processes, so you can use `sudo snap stop redis` to stop the redis server from snap.